# Appium press and move_to element

Tags: ruby, appium

I have an application, and it works such way: when I tap & hold some element, context menu is shown, then I can move my finger to specified element and release it on appropriate menu item. I try implement this logic with Appium, but it's failed.

At first, I tried `press` element, then `move_to` another:

```
Appium::TouchAction.new.press(element: my_elem).perform
Appium::TouchAction.new.move_to(element: text(...)).perform
```

But before second action "finger releases screen" and context menu disappeared. Then I tried another way:

```
Appium::TouchAction.new
    .press(element: my_elem)
    .move_to(element: text(...))
    .perform
```

But it fails with `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: No element found`, because element, where we `move_to`, didn't appeared yet.

So, tell me please, how can I implement neccessary logic?

Comment: Have you already implemented this? I am facing the same scenario but considering your case, is there a built in function for `long press`?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Ruby but in java first you `release()` it before `perform()`. Also, if this doesn't work, look if duration() method is availabe in Ruby. Then you should use somethings like:

```
element.longPress.duration.release.perform();
```

In case if you don't find duration method, then its a bug in Appium what they are working on. Look at this:

https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/4695

Comment: I tried `Appium::TouchAction.new.press(element: my_elem).move_to(element: text(...)).release.perform`
but result is the same as in the second case: `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError`. Element searching in `move_to` works too early and it produce this error, I think.

Comment: What does `duration` do? There is a `long_press` method in Ruby, and it has both `element` and `duration` options. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: element is your variable of TouchAction class. longPress, put some duration on it, release() and then perform. This should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.scrollTo("string").tap(1,2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that the element you want move to is really reachable.  If it is but it hasn't appeared before you called the method then you should wait till the element appears. This is a sample in java

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(locator));
```

This may look a little different in your case, but the idea is the same. After it passes, then call `move_to`, if it fails then probably your element is not reachable.

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is like you said,

> But it fails with Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: No element found, because element, where we move_to, didn't appeared yet.

Then try this

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new :timeout => 10
```

then you can do something like this

```
wait.until { moveTo(element: text(...)) } ...
```

You probably have to adapt this to your case, I just wanted to show you the idea, you can read more about this [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp)